# textboxes alignment messing up when required validators fire?

Tags: asp.net, html, css, alignment

I have table with couple of textboxes in it. In those 2 fields I have required fields. When validators fire alignment is changing. Before the validators fire, textboxes aligntment is good.

Pic1 for after validator fires. 
[image]

Pic2 for before validator fires.

[image]

Here is the HTML.

```
<table class="Borderblue" id="Table26" cellspacing="3" align="center" style="width: 100%;">
 <tr>
    <td bgcolor="White" style="width:20%" >
            First Name  <br/> 
            (on website)                                 
    </td>
     <td bgcolor="White" style="width:20%" >
           Middle Intial <br/> 
                 (on website) 
      </td>

      <td bgcolor="White" style="width:20%" >
              Last Name <br/> 
              (on website) 
      </td>
       <td bgcolor="White" style="width:20%" >
              Nick Name <br/> 
              (Goes By Name) 
       </td>  
    </tr>                               
     <tr>
         <td bgcolor="White" style="width:20%" >
             <asp:TextBox ID="txt6_2" runat="server" CssClass="TextBox SmallText" ></asp:TextBox>
              <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" id="RequiredFieldValidator8" ValidationGroup="ValidateInsert" Display="Dynamic" controltovalidate="txt6_2" errormessage="Please enter first name!" />
         </td>
         <td bgcolor="White" style="width:20%">
             <asp:TextBox ID="txt7_2" runat="server" CssClass="TextBox SmallText" MaxLength="2" Width="20px" style="vertical-align:top"  ></asp:TextBox>
        </td>                           
        <td bgcolor="White" style="width:20%">
               <asp:TextBox ID="txt8_2" runat="server" CssClass="TextBox SmallText"></asp:TextBox>
              <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" id="RequiredFieldValidator9" ValidationGroup="ValidateInsert" Display="Dynamic" controltovalidate="txt8_2" errormessage="Please enter last name!" />
            </td>                           
            <td bgcolor="White" style="width:20%" >
             <asp:TextBox ID="txt9_2" runat="server" CssClass="TextBox SmallText" width="120px"></asp:TextBox>                                                                            </td>            
      </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.SmallText
{
     font-family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica;
     text-align:justify;    
    font-size: 8.5pt;
 }
    .TextBox
    {
           Width: 100px;
           Height:12px;
           background-color:#F0F0F0;
           border: 1px solid #000000;
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably need to move the validators to their own cells so the text box cells aren't expanded. Or valign="top" on your cells might work.